# How to correctly setup Flask + uWSGI + SQLAlchemy to avoid database connection issues

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, uwsgi

I am using a Flask app with SQLAlchemy and a uWSGI server. It is a known issue that uWSGI's duplicates connection through all the processes during forking. The information about how to fix this issue is a bit scatted in the web, but the two main options seems to be:

- Using `lazy-apps = true` within uWSGI's config (Which is not recommended because it consumes a lot of memory)
- Using uWSGI's `@postfork` decorator to close the connection after forking to start new fresh connections for each new process, but it's unclear for me when and how should be used within the Flask app.

This the sample of my app:

```
# file: my_app/app.py

db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_pyfile(f'../config/settings.py')
    db.init_app(app)
    db.create_all(app=app)
    return app
```

Sample of the **run.py** file:

```
# file: run.py
from my_app/app import create_app


app = create_app()
if "__main__" == __name__:
    app.run(debug=app.config["DEBUG"], port=5000)
```

So the question is where and how should the postfork executed to properly setup uWSGI's server to use isolated connections on each process without using `lazy-apps = true`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy manual provides two examples how to approach this: [Using Connection Pools with Multiprocessing](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#using-connection-pools-with-multiprocessing).

The first approach involving `Engine.dispose()` can be approached using `uwsgidecorators.postfork` as suggested by Hett - simple example that should work if there's only the default binding involved:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgres:///test"
    db.init_app(app)

    def _dispose_db_pool():
        with app.app_context():
            db.engine.dispose()

    try:
        from uwsgidecorators import postfork
        postfork(_dispose_db_pool)
    except ImportError:
        # Implement fallback when running outside of uwsgi...
        raise

    return app
```

The second one involves `sqlalchemy.event` and discarding connections from different PIDs - quoting:

> The next approach is to instrument the Pool itself with events so that connections are automatically invalidated in the subprocess. This is a little more magical but probably more foolproof.

If you want the latter magical solution, see the docs.

Comment: I have chosen this as the right answer because it clearly explains the available options and how postfork can be directly applied to my provided code. Thanks a lot @Arne Welzel

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to use @postfork decorator provided by uwsgi.
We are not using SQLAlchemy, but I think you can adapt our solution to your case as well.

Here's an excerpt from our uwsgi configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
strict = true

; process management
master = true
vacuum = true
pidfile = /tmp/uwsgi.pid

enable-threads = true
cpu-affinity = 1
processes = 4
threads = 2
mules = 2
...
```

And here's the application initialization code using @postfork to create process safe DB connections.

```
from flask import Flask
from uwsgidecorators import postfork

from app.lib.db import DB  # DB object will be replaced by SQLAlchemy on your side

app = Flask(__name__)

# due to uwsgi's copy-on-write semantics workers need to connect to database
# to preserve unique descriptors after fork() is called in master process
@postfork
def db_reconnect():
    # Open the DB connection and log the event
    app.db = DB(config.get('db', 'host'),
                config.get('db', 'user'),
                config.get('db', 'pass'),
                config.get('db', 'name'))
```

In our case all initialization code is placed in `__init__.py` or `app` folder, but I don't think you'll have any difficulties to migrate it into your `app.py` file.

Let me know if you'll encounter any other questions on this.