# SQLalchemy can't communicate to MySQL server upon app start

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, uwsgi

I'm have troubles with SQLalchemy in Flask app first minute after the app start (or restart).
It looks like logger exceptions of a sort:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away') <---- most often one

> sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column 'users.id'"

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column 'payments.id'"

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

Then everything gets back to normal. It's not a critical issue but annoying.

I tried to run warming up queries upon application start:

```
    with app.app_context():
        for _ in range(5):
            try:
                db.session.execute(statement)
                logger.info("DB connection is successfully established")
                return
            except Exception as e:
                logger.warning(e)
                time.sleep(1)
    raise Exception("Couldn't establish a DB connection")
```

It passes through just fine but then I see same issues.

It doesn't happen in development environment, only in production where Flask app runs on uwsgi server. Is there a way to fix it?

Update: connection URI looks like this: `"mysql+mysqldb://user:password@localhost/mydb?unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"`

Comment: I'm not sure how to reproduce the issue because I can't reproduce it myself - it only appears on the production server. Only difference with dev is UWSGI on prod

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59492567/12502959 did you get to try this and / or other suggestions there?

Comment: Can you share your uwsgi config? This is a common issue with uwsgi forking, you can try setting lazy-apps = true there or implement postfork

Comment: > stackoverflow.com/a/59492567/12502959 did you get to try this and / or other suggestions there?

Indeed that had helped. Thanks a lot! You can post it as an answer for it to be accepted as one.

Comment: @Ralfeus glad to have helped. Just did, I believe I have given enough attribution to the original source as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems [How to correctly setup Flask + uWSGI + SQLAlchemy to avoid database connection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248806/how-to-correctly-setup-flask-uwsgi-sqlalchemy-to-avoid-database-connection-i/59492567#59492567) worked for them. This is a copy paste of the answer just to avoid "link only answers". I would still recommend anyone arriving at this question to refer the original answer linked above.

> The SQLAlchemy manual provides two examples how to approach this: Using Connection Pools with Multiprocessing. The first approach involving Engine.dispose() can be approached using uwsgidecorators.postfork as suggested by Hett - simple example that should work if there's only the default binding involved:

```py
    db = SQLAlchemy()

    def create_app():
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgres:///test"
        db.init_app(app)
        
        def _dispose_db_pool():
            with app.app_context():
                db.engine.dispose()

        try:
            from uwsgidecorators import postfork
            postfork(_dispose_db_pool)
        except ImportError:
            # Implement fallback when running outside of uwsgi...
            raise

        return app
```

Meta: I am posting this as an answer as per OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634768/sqlalchemy-cant-communicate-to-mysql-server-upon-app-start#comment137530722_77634768)